# Why is my rollback rejected here?

Tags: support, review, edits, suggested-edits, rollbacks

Please see this question: [How to view html output in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283241/why-are-there-always/22283275#22283275)

The OP edited his question to a completely different one, so my answer is now invalid and is starting to attract downvotes.

I tried to edit this back into the original question, and because I don't have the edit privilege I had to wait until someone accepted this edit.

The edit was rejected and the question is still the same.

Now I'm stuck: I can't delete my answer because it is accepted, and my attempts to undo the changes made by the OP have failed. What should I do?

Comment: It's really hard to tell that a big rollback is a valid edit since it always looks like a radical change. Theres a feature-request somewhere to make it more obvious when a suggestion is a rollback.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This was your suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4401750), which had this edit reason:

> please don't ask another question; in the same question.

Now that really doesn't make it obvious to reviewers what you're doing. To them, it really looks like *you* are the one completely changing the question. In the future, try more descriptive reasons to tell people exactly what is changing:

> Rolling back to original question after OP completely changed it.

I have a hard time believing it would get rejected if that reason had been used.

Comment: Taking into account the quality of too many reviewers these days, I won't have hard time believing any valid edit will be rejected and any crappy edit being approved. But yeah, in ideal system it's true. :)